# How I can better design my code regarding text on my website it always overlap with the picture on my mobile but looks nice on laptop

Tags: html, css

hello every one I need help in finding the best way to solve my problem with text as it look ugly on mobile phone but look ok on laptop as I am attaching the screen shot of laptop and mobile phone to solve the over lap ing of text over the image, In the laptop I use 
 to move the text to next line I know it is not the best approach but I could not find any better one this the screen shot of my phone and laptop [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed5al.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa432.jpg)

and also the code of the website html and css

Characters

```
</head>
<body class ="background">
     <nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark border">
        <ul class = "navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2">

            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a id="navigation" class = "nav-link" href = "index.html">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a id="navigation" class = "nav-link" href = "introduction.html">
                    Introduction
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a id="navigation" class = "nav-link" href = "Characters.html">
                    Characters
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a id="navigation" class = "nav-link" href = "bibliography.html">
                    Reference
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </nav>
    <main>
        <div class = "chr_text">

            <p>
                <h3 class ="underline">
                    Natsu Dragneel
                </h3>
                <img src ="natsu.jpg" alt="Natsu" class="move_right">
                Natsu is a Young man of average Height with a muscular body and slight Tan skin.<br> He has spiky pink- coloured hair and sharp canines. He is a Wizard in a guild <br> called Fairy tail, beside this he is also a member of Team Natsu. His magic <br> abilities include Fire Dragon  Slayer Magic, Natsu has adapted with his Fire Dragon <br> Slayer Magic to make use of it in  many combats. The heat of his fire can increase in <br> temperature, which is directly proportional to Natsu's emotional state. Natsu also <br> has the ability to eat flames give him immunity to most types of flames, including explosions <br> and allows him to Spew fire from his lungs
            </p>

        </div>
       <hr class ="line">

       <div class ="chr_text">
            <p>
                <h3 class ="underline">
                    Lucy Heartfilia
                </h3>
                <img src="lucy.jpg" alt="Lucy" class="move_right">

                Lucy Heartfilia is a fictional character and the protagonist of fairy tail manga created <br> by Hiro Mashima. Lucy uses magical objects known as Gatekeys to invite celestial <br> spirits, from another world that own varied capabilities, such as powerful zodiac spirits <br> that she invite with rare golden keys.She is the teenager debutante of the wealthy <br> Heartfilia family who tackle on a journey to join the Fairy Tail, which she fulfills <br> after Natsu Dragneel rescues her from a slave trader present as a Fairy Tail member <br> under his own pet name of "Salamander". She is also a pursuing novelist who <br> eventually publishes her launch novel based on her experiences at the guild at the end <br> of the series.

            </p>
       </div>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <hr class="line">
       <div class="chr_text">
           <p>
               <h3 class="underline">
                    Erza scarlet
               </h3>
               <img src ="erza.jpg" alt ="Erza" class="move_right">

               Erza is a young woman with long, scarlet hair and brown eyes. She lost her right eye <br> as a child and now has an artificial one which was created by Porlyusica. She has <br> a slender, voluptuous figure that Lucy Heartfilia described as "amazing." Her most <br> common attire consists of a custom-made armor by Heart Kreuz smiths, a blue skirt, <br>  black boots, and diamond shaped silver earrings. Her Fairy Tail stamp is blue and is <br>  located on the middle of her left upper arm .Erza's specialty in Requip Magic allows <br>  her to requip not only armors but different outfits as well, enabling her to change her <br> attire at any given time.

           </p>

       </div>
       <hr>

    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Paragraph elements cannot contain heading elements also

Comment: Did some cleaning with flex: https://jsfiddle.net/jtzvaw95/ , but your probably better off with a grid.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<br>` tags in the paragraphs, as they mark the position of the line break. Instead, omitting them, text in HTML flows and adapts to the shape of the browser window. Not only for mobiles, there are small laptops, or even huge screens in which the user puts windows side by side.

Also probably if you put in your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It will provide you a more natural text size for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using rows and columns to organize your text and images and maybe use bootstrap to make the images responsive. For example:

```
<div class="character">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
             <p>Character description</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col">
             <img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Also, add to the `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Hopefully, this helps, and good luck!

Comment: ok this helped a lot but I did not quite get that if you just named the class col or row then it dose not become a row or a column why not I use the table built in the table in html it is getting quite confusing

Comment: Hi, glad I could help a bit. If you want the "row" and "col" tags to work, then you need to add the bootstrap link to the head of your Html file. For more information on how to use the grid system, go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/